# Select/detect the changed elements in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The example looks like this:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5];
svg.selectAll("rect").data(a)
a[1]=10;
a[4]=50;
svg.selectAll("rect").data(a)
```

The second and the fifth elements of `a` are changed. And I want to ONLY select these two elements and set their color as red. However, I don't know how to do that, or in other words, select these changed element in d3.js. (As I understand, `enter()` can't do this job). Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a way to store the old data value so that you can compare it against the new one.  Maybe add a custom data attribute like this:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5];
svg.selectAll("rect").data(a)
    .attr("data-currentVal", function(d){return d});
a[1]=10;
a[4]=50;
svg.selectAll("rect").data(a)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
       if (d3.select(this).attr("data-currentVal") != d) {return red;}
       else {return black;}
    });
```

Live example (slightly fancied up so you can see the changes happening):
http://fiddle.jshell.net/5Jm5w/1/

Of course, for the more common example where d is a complex object, you would need to have a way of accessing it's value(s) as a unique string, since the attribute value would always be coerced to string.  For example, if you have an (x,y) point, you would need to create a named helper function like `dToString = function(d) {return "(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";}`, and then pass in the name of that function when you set the attribute, and use it again when you compare the old and new.

Answer (score 7):

There might be a better way of doing this:

```
//update data array
a[4]=50;

//color update elements
svg.selectAll('rect')
    .filter(function(d, i){ return d != a[i]; })
    .style('color', 'red')

//bind updated data
svg.selectAll('rect').data(a)
```

Comment: Well, that's a short and sweet alternative.  A bit counter-intuitive, to update the style before updating the data, but it should do it.  Only problem I can see is if (a) you set a long transition on the style change and (b) you are dealing with live interactive events, then things might get out of order.

Comment: Another potential issue: if you have an array of objects instead of primitives and update the data in place - a[0].value = 100; - .datum() of each DOM element will also update and filter won't find any differences.