# Compare/Diff new data with previous data on d3.js update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to represent the *difference* between the current data set and the previous data set, as calculated by the client.

Imagine I already have three circles, bound to the data `[1, 2, 3]`. Now I'd like to update the data and do something based on the difference between the new values and the old?

```
var new_data = [2, 2, 2]; // This is the new data I'd like to compare with the old

svg.selectAll("circle").data(new_data)
    .transition().duration(2000)
.attr("fill", "red") // e.g. I'd like to colour the circles red if the change
                     // is negative, blue if positive, black if no change.
.attr("r", function(d) { return d * 10; });
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YJ2Ws/15/) with the above code set into an example.

Comment: D3 doesn't save the old data, so you would have to keep it around and compare yourself.

Comment: Any advice on how to best to do this? Is it a good idea, for example, to save the previous data as an attribute on the DOM element? Or is that somehow frowned upon?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have two options for saving the old data attached to an element in order to identify changes after a new data join.

The first option, as you suggested, is to use data attributes. [This SO Q&A describes that approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765847/3128209).  Things to consider:

- all your data values will get coerced to strings
- you'll need a separate method call/attribute for each aspect of the data
- you're manipulating the DOM, so it could slow things down if you've got a lot of elements or lot of data for each
- the data is now part of the DOM, so can be saved with the image or accessed by other scripts

The second option is to store the data as a Javascript property of the DOM object for the element, in the same way that d3 [stores the active data as the `__data__` property](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data).  I've discussed this method in [this forum post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/w11PXct8jPI/4S8uO4c-l9QJ).

The general approach:

```
selection = selection.property(" __oldData__", function(d){ return d; } ); 
                        //store the old data as a property of the node
                    .data(newData, dataKeyFunction);  
                        //over-write the default data property with new data
                        //and store the new data-joined selection in your variable

selection.enter() /*etc*/;  

selection.attr("fill",  function(d) {
                 // Within any d3 callback function,
                 // you can now compare `d` (the new data object)
                 // with `this.__oldData__` (the old data object).
                 // Just remember to check whether `this.__oldData__` exists
                 // to account for the just-entered elements.

                if (this.__oldData__) { //old data exists

                  var dif = d.value - this.__oldData__.value; 
                  return (dif) ? //is dif non-zero?
                         ( (dif > 0)? "blue" : "red" ) :
                         "black" ; 
                } else {
                  return "green"; //value for new data
                }

            });

selection.property("__oldData__", null); 
          //delete the old data once it's no longer needed
          //(not required, but a good idea if it's using up a lot of memory)
```

You can of course use any name for the old data property, it's just convention to throw a lot of "_" characters around it to avoid messing up any of the browser's native DOM properties.

Comment: Genius. Perfect answer as far as I'm concerned. +1 for teaching me why it's not a good idea to write data to the DOM.

Comment: Fixed the link.  There are times when creating data attributes has benefits -- e.g. see [this Q&A on attaching data to an SVG built server-side](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23096459/3128209) -- but if you don't need it, just using plain Javascript object properties is more efficient.

Answer (score 12):

As of D3 **v4** you can use the built-in support for [local variables](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#local-variables). The internal implementation is basically the same as suggested by AmeliaBR's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23411456/4235784), but it frees you from having to do the storing of old data on your own. When using [`d3.local()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#local) you can [set](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#local_set) a value scoped to a specific DOM node, hence the name *local* variable. In below snippet this is done for each circle by the line

```
.each(function(d) { previousData.set(this, d) });  // Store previous data locally...
```

You can later on [retrieve](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#local_get) that value for any particular node it was stored upon:

```
.attr("fill", function(d) {
  var diff = previousData.get(this) - d;  // Retrieve previously stored data.
  return diff  < 0 ? "red" : diff > 0 ? "blue" : "black";
})
```

This full code might look something like this:

```js
var old_data = [1, 2, 3]; // When the data gets updated I'd like to 'remember' these values

// Create a local variable for storing previous data.
var previousData = d3.local();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 200);

var p = d3.select("body")
  .append("p")
    .text("Old data. Click on the circles to update the data.");

var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(old_data)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d * 10; })
    .attr("cx", function(d){ return d * 40; })
    .attr("cy", function(d){ return d * 40; })
    .each(function(d) { previousData.set(this, d) });  // Store previous data locally on each node

svg.on("click", function(d) {
  p.text("Updated data.");
  var new_data = [2, 2, 2]; // This is the new data I'd like to compare with the old
    
  circle.data(new_data)
    .transition().duration(2000)
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        var diff = previousData.get(this) - d;  // Retrieve previously stored data.
        return diff  < 0 ? "red" : diff > 0 ? "blue" : "black";
      }) 
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d * 10; });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Comment: This seems like the right approach nowadays. Can a third party confirm that this should be my chosen answer?

Comment: As this is a rather old question, I think, you will need to somehow bump it to get some attention or confirmation. It is a new feature introduced by v4 and has the advantage of keeping things confined to the D3 universe. We have just recently seen a similar question ([*"How to access previous data value before binding the new value in d3.js?"*](/q/41265463)), which I think duplicates this one. Hence, I decided to post this as a v4 complement to @AmeliaBR's answer, which is applicable to D3 <v4.

Comment: Definitely the way to go as of v4, however the documentation does state ***If you are just setting a single variable, consider using selection.property:*** So the accepted answer could still be considered correct in some cases.